# indexing multidimensional array in python

Tags: python, indexing

I have an array like below and I want to keep only the 3rd element for each row.

Input

`array(['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'],........['an', 'bn', 'cn'])`

Expected output

`array('c', 'c1', ...... 'cn')`

I tried it using a for loop but it is taking too long. Is there a faster way to do this? Can someone please help?

Comment: Please show your loop and timings, maybe you did something wrong. In any case, check out the itertools module and consider generators instead of arrays or lists.

Comment: How are you creating that array? The [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) module doesn't have multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean a `list` when you mention an `array`.

This would be the code:

```
>>> my_list = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'], ['an', 'bn', 'cn']]
>>> [x[2] for x in my_list]
['c', 'c1', 'cn']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
[x[2] for x in my_list]
```

pointed out by Gab is correct, however if you are making use of an numpy array, this will be probably more efficent:

```
x[:,2]
```